# Не удается добавить элементы в свг динамически

Tags: jquery, svg

Добавляю следующий код(пытаюсь добавить элемент в svg) но не получется,поясните как поправить

```
$("#vmap svg path").prepend('<defs><pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="450"><image xlink:href="daisy-grass-repeating-background.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="450" /></pattern></defs>')
    $("#vmap svg path").each(function(i,e){
       $(e).attr("fill","url(#img1)")
    })

<div id="vmap">
  <svg>
      <path d="M5,50
             l0,100 l100,0 l0,-100 l-100,0
             M215,100
             a50,50 0 1 1 -100,0 50,50 0 1 1 100,0
             M265,50
             l50,100 l-100,0 l50,-100
             z"
          fill="url(#img1)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: У SVG элементов свой namespace. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7547117

Answer (score 2):

jQuery, к сожалению, [не умеет создавать элементы SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894377/dynamically-adding-a-svg-gradient). Поэтому придется по старинке, через JS:

```js
//Элементы заливки
var pattern = makeSVG('pattern', {
  id: 'img1',
patternUnits:'userSpaceOnUse',
  width: '600',
  height: '450',
  x: '0',
  y: '0'
})

var img1 = makeSVG('image', {
  'href': 'https://placeimg.com/600/450/any',
  width: '600',
  height: '450',
  x: '0',
  y: '0'
})

//добавляем defs, если его нет
svg = $('#vmap svg')[0];

var defs = svg.querySelector('defs') ||
  svg.insertBefore(makeSVG('defs'), svg.firstChild);

defs.appendChild(pattern);
pattern.appendChild(img1);

//настраиваем стиль 
$("#vmap svg path").each(function(i, e) {
  $(e).attr("style", "fill:url(#img1)")
})

//небольшая функция для упрощения жизни
function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
  var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
  for (var k in attrs)
    el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
  return el;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vmap">
  <svg>

      <path d="M5,50
             l0,100 l100,0 l0,-100 l-100,0
             M215,100
             a50,50 0 1 1 -100,0 50,50 0 1 1 100,0
             M265,50
             l50,100 l-100,0 l50,-100
             z"
          style="fill:url(#img1)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```